# While read from line in shell script sh linux

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, sh

I am reading from a file in sh shell script and I want to remove one line from the file if the condition succeeds.

```
if [ -f "file.txt" ]; then
     while read line
     do
          if [*condition...*]; then
                *remove line from file*
     done
fi
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? When I run the script now it gives no output (if I try with echo inside the while loop) and never ends...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `while read line`... but not reading properly. You may need to change your `done` for `done < file.txt`:

```
if [ -f "file.txt" ]; then
     while read line
     do
          if [ *condition...*]; then
                *remove line from file*
     done < file.txt  # <------------- here!
fi
```